# signal handling in golang with network programming

Tags: go, networking

Trying to learn golang network programming. Implemented simple
server with unix domain sockets. The server has:

1. taskChan: Unbuf channel for client connection object.
2. sigChan: buf channel for signals
3. srvDone: unbuf channel to indicate server done.
4. blocks all async signals except SIGINT/SIGHUP.

Then starts signalHandler(), three taskWorker(), acceptClientReqs()
in goroutines. On receiving the signal (send the signal to this process with kill -SIGINT ), the signal handler sets global variable **serverShutdown**. My intention is - all the goroutines to read **serverShutdown** and exit cleanly. However, some times all the worker
threads exiting and other times they don't. Do you see any bug in my code?
Or am I missing some thing?

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "fmt"
import "net"
import "os"
import "os/signal"
import "syscall"
import "time"

var srvShutdown = false

type netServer struct {
    listener     *net.UnixListener // unix local sock
    taskChan     chan net.Conn     // unbuf channel for client connections
    sigChan      chan os.Signal    // buffered channel
    srvDone      chan bool
    numOfWorkers int
}

// initialize signals.
func initSignals() {
    // block all async signals to this server except SIGINT/SIGHUP
    signal.Ignore()
}

// initializes server:
//   1) creates listener.
//   2) creates task channel - client connections accepted on this channel.
//   3) initializes few other things such as signal channel, num of workers etc.
func initServer() (*netServer, error) {
    sockAddr, err := net.ResolveUnixAddr("unix", "/tmp/unix.socket")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("initServer() failed on ResolveUnixAddr(): ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    srvlistener, err := net.ListenUnix("unix", sockAddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("initServer() failed on ListenUnix(): ", err)
        return nil, err
    }
    netSrv := &netServer{
        listener:     srvlistener,
        taskChan:     make(chan net.Conn),
        sigChan:      make(chan os.Signal, 1),
        srvDone:      make(chan bool),
        numOfWorkers: 3,
    }
    initSignals()
    return netSrv, nil
}

// Accept client connections. Each connection is directed onto
// a channel. Worker threads pickup and work on these connections.
func (netSrv *netServer) acceptClientReqs() {
    fmt.Println("Listening on /tmp/unix.socket")
    for srvShutdown != true {
        netSrv.listener.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Second))
        conn, err := netSrv.listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Accept failed : ", err)
            continue
        }
        netSrv.taskChan <- conn
    }
    netSrv.srvDone <- true
    fmt.Println("Exiting server")
}

// Pickup a client connection, work on it and close connection.
func (netSrv *netServer) taskWorker(workerId int) {
    fmt.Println("taskWorker(): starting worker-", workerId)
    // for conn := range netSrv.taskChan {
    for srvShutdown != true {
        conn := <-netSrv.taskChan
        if conn == nil {
            fmt.Println("taskWorker(): worker-", workerId, " continue")
            continue
        }
        fmt.Println("taskWorker(): worker-", workerId, " processing client connection: ", conn)
        dec := json.NewDecoder(conn)
        var Cmd string
        dec.Decode(&Cmd)
        fmt.Println(" cmd: ", Cmd)

        // reply to client
        _, err := conn.Write([]byte("AUTH SUCCESS"))
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        conn.Close()
        fmt.Println("taskWorker(): worker-", workerId, " processed client connection: ", conn)
    }
    fmt.Println("taskWorker(): exiting worker-", workerId)
}

// Handle SIGINT and SIGHUP for now.
func (netSrv *netServer) signalHandler() {
    signal.Notify(netSrv.sigChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGHUP)
    sig := <-netSrv.sigChan
    fmt.Println("signalHandler() received signal", sig)
    srvShutdown = true
}

func (netSrv *netServer) cleanUp() {
    close(netSrv.taskChan)
    netSrv.listener.Close()
    close(netSrv.srvDone)
}

func main() {
    srv, err := initServer()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("initServer() failed - ", err)
        return
    }
    go srv.signalHandler()

    for i := 1; i <= srv.numOfWorkers; i++ {
        go srv.taskWorker(i)
    }
    go srv.acceptClientReqs()

    // wait server to complete
    <-srv.srvDone
    srv.cleanUp()
}
```

Comment: What is output after `signalHandler() received signal`?  I don't believe `signal.Ignore()` is actually ignoring anything, so it's possible another signal is received before `SIGINT` or `SIGHUP`

Comment: You have a data race. Run your code through shutdown with the race detector.

Comment: Setting a global var like this is not thread-safe. Generally in Go you would use a channel to signal shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. After protecting the global variable the problem went away. Also thanks for the tip to use race detector.